# How to build a One war for multiple project in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, maven, terminal, war

I have a 3 Project files 
1)FirstFile(contain Beans and dao files)
2)SecondFile-API(properties file)
3)ThirdFile-Service(all controller)

I want to make a war file of my Eclipse Project How can i build the war file for this projects.

Comment: Wrap them into the `.ear`.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Maven to generate a prototype project that will build a war.

```
mvn archetype:generate |grep webapp

remote -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp (An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project.)
```

Add your submodules and dependencies to the prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache Maven Shade Plugin

> an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html